# Is it possible to split a wave function experimentally? Aren't we able to access only the observables of the quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In one of the problems in 8.04 (MIT) related to scattering matrix, the question was to design an experiment which measures $\mid{t}\mid^{2}$ . Design another experiment which measures the phase of $t$. where $t$ is the transmission amplitude of the wave function and $\mid{t}\mid^{2}$ is the transmission probability of the particle appearing past the potential.

The experiment of measuring $\mid{t}\mid^{2}$ is straightforward.

But for measuring the phase of $t$, I couldn't thing of an solution and looked into the solutions that they've given and it says this.

[image]

My Question:
How is it possible to split the wave function using a beam splitter or am I understanding the question wrong?

Links:
[8.04 Solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/assignments/MIT8_04S13_ps7_sol.pdf)
[8.04 Question](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/assignments/MIT8_04S13_ps7.pdf)

Question: 4a

Comment: I'm not an expert but, supposing that we have the technology to do it (which seems like it after a google search), you could. In fact we surely can do it with light so why not with other particles

Comment: Gratings split beams. Have you searched on the internet?

Comment: gratings split wave functions!. I didn't know that.